# Two foreignkeys for one field in djangomodel

Tags: django-models, django-orm

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this problem I've made for my self.

I have these two customer models, with some similar and some different fields. I want either of these two to be assigned as ForeignKey to a field in my projectclass.

The idea is, that when the user creates a project, the user can choose from all customers and assign from both private and company customers for that particular field, but not having to specifiy anywhere beforehand what kind of customer it is.

Private customer

```
class PrivateCustomer(models.Model):
    .. fields
```

Company Customer

```
class CompanyCustomer(models.Model):
    ...
```

Project

```
class Project(models.Model):
    customer = model.ForeignKey(PrivateCustomer,CompanyCustomer)
```

Can I make a join of the two for that particular field, on the fly, as instance occurs or should I just drop the seperation between the two customer classes and handle this through UI inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having both fields with condition *null = True*

```
class Project(models.Model):
    privateCustomer = models.ForeignKey(PrivateCustomer, null = True)
    companyCustomer = models.ForeignKey(CompanyCustomer , null = True)
```

And then from your views, you can handle them easily.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it seems like the best solution.